# Short cut key to edit from start of cell (instead of f2 for end)

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts

I have Excel sheets where the cells have long formulae or pieces of text that I am editing but the bits to edit are generally at the start of the cell. The F2 shortcut lets you edit the cell put it places the cursor at the end of the cell contents. Is there a shortcut to edit the cell with the cursor at the start rather than the end of the contents?

Comment: <f2><home> is as short as it gets

Comment: Thanks. I suspected that might be the case but I thought it was worth an ask :)

Comment: Move Cell pointer (the Cross bar) to the left most position on cell ,, double click mouse,, if wnna to edit in Formula bar then `File,, Options,, Advanced,, Editing Options,, Uncheck Allow Editing Directly In Cell.`

Comment: According to [Keyboard shortcuts in Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/keyboard-shortcuts-in-excel-1798d9d5-842a-42b8-9c99-9b7213f0040f), there seems to be no such keyboard shortcut in Excel to do that. I think you can press ESC to exit the Edit mode. Then you can edit the cell at the start  by using mouse to click the cell again.

Comment: You can also use [AHK](http://autohotkey.org/) and define a hotkey that inputs in sequence F2 followed by Ctrl+Home?

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is. After you press F2, press the home key.

Answer (score 2):

A couple options:

- Press <kbd>F2</kbd>, once cursor is blinking, press <kbd>Home</kbd>. This will put the cursor at the beginning of the last line.

[image: Cursor at beginning of last line]

- Press <kbd>F2</kbd>, once cursor is blinking, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd>. This will put the cursor at the very beginning of the cell (when there are multiple lines).

[image: Cursor at beginning of cell]